# Django - how to not loose verbose_name and other attributes of Field when overriding its form in ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

Given:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.IntegerField('Detailed description')

#forms.py
from django import forms
from models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = forms.IntegerField()


class Meta:
    model = MyModel
```

With this setup - verbose_name will not be shown on admin page, name of field will be instead (with capitalized first letter). If remove overriding field from MyModelForm - verbose name will be shown as usual. If provide string with description as argument `label`, `forms.IntegerField()` - it will be displayed on admin page.
Im looking for pythonic way to display verbose_name defined in model class in case if this field form is overrided in ModelForm, without using `label` hint.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no direct way to do this that I'm aware of - if you specify a field manually in your form declaration, you have to set everything about it.  One common workaround when you only want to change the behavior from the default field a little bit is to use the form's `__init__` method to edit field properties.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the verbose name of the model in the form like this:

```
myfield = models.IntegerField(label=MyModel._meta.get_field_by_name('myfield')[0].verbose_name)
```